# React context not updating component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i have two components that need to be able to read and change the context of a list
but when one of them updates the context the other one doesn't update

is there a better way to do this other than the context hook?
if there is not why doesn't it update and how do i fix it?

```
const WebsiteContext = createContext([]);

const WebsiteContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);

  return (
    <WebsiteContext.Provider value={[cards, setCards]}>
      {props.children}
    </WebsiteContext.Provider>
  );
};

function LayersPanel(props) {
  const [cards, setCards] = useContext(WebsiteContext);
  return (
    <Box className="layersPanel">
      {cards.map((item) => (
        <h1 className="layer">{item.name}</h1>
      ))}
    </Box>
  );
}
function ControlPanel(props) {
  return (
    <div className="ControlPanel">
      <h1>hello world</h1>
      <LayersPanel></LayersPanel>
    </div>
  );
}

function WebsiteBody(props) {
  const [cards, setCards] = useContext(WebsiteContext);

  const [{ droppedItem, didDrop, isOver, canDrop }, drop] = useDrop(() => ({
    accept: "card",
    drop: () => ({
      name: "WebsiteBody",
    }),
    collect: (monitor) => ({
      droppedItem: monitor.getItem(),
      didDrop: monitor.didDrop(),
    }),
  }));
  if (didDrop) {
    const tempCardName =
      droppedItem.card.name + " " + (item_id === 0 ? "" : item_id.toString());

    const tempCard = droppedItem.card;
    tempCard.name = tempCardName;

    const temp_cards = cards;
    temp_cards.push(tempCard);

    setCards(temp_cards);

    item_id += 1;
  }

  return (
    <Box ref={drop} w="100vw" h="100vh" backgroundColor="yellow.400" display="flex">
      {cards.map((item) => item.component.code)}
    </Box>
  );
}

let item_id = 0;

function WebsiteEditor(props) {
  return (
    <ChakraProvider>
      <DndProvider backend={HTML5Backend}>
        <WebsiteContextProvider>
          <WebsiteBody></WebsiteBody>
          <ControlPanel></ControlPanel>
        </WebsiteContextProvider>
      </DndProvider>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: seems like the LayersPanel component might not be a child of the WebsiteContextProvider component (unless the LayersPanel component is a child of the ControlPanel component?), they need to be children of the same context provider

Comment: it is a child of ControlPanel component

Answer (score 0):

- You should `useMemo` any non-simple value provided by a Provider; otherwise it will be recomputed on every render.
- You aren't calling `setCards` with a new object, but mutating `cards` internally. Use e.g. `setCards([...cards, tempCard]);` to make sure you're using a new object.
- You're similarly internally mutating the `card` that is dropped. You can make a shallow copy with `const tempCard = {...droppedItem.card};` (and you can combine the name change in there: `{...droppedItem.card, name: tempCardName}`)
- Using a global variable like your `item_id` is not idiomatic React. Consider a random ID, or one based on time, or if you really do need sequential IDs, it should also be part of state.
- You may wish to consider `useReducer` instead of the `useState` pair for your  contexted state.